# Pass dots with htaccess to PHP file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create system, that will check file before it proceed to user.

This is my main line in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ ./getfile.php?hash=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is in `getfile.php` file:

```
print_r($_GET['hash']);
```

Both of these files are in separated folder named `get`.

So, when I try this URL:

```
http://localhost/example/get/information
```

Then it prints `information` - that's what I was expecting.

But, when I try this URL (there could be more `information` files):

```
http://localhost/example/get/information.txt
```

This prints Error 404. My files are stored in secured folder, so there is no dirrect access to any file. For example, only logged in users will be able to download these files.

So, how can I edit any file, so `$_GET['hash']` will contains `information.txt`?

PS: Don't suggest me better ways, I want it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your rule with:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ getfile.php?hash=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your regex `[^/.]+` is only grabbing text before a DOT.

Comment: This helped, but not really much, because I tried `http://localhost/example/get/information.txt` and it redirects me few times and URL become `http://localhost/example/get/information.txt/////////////////////`

Comment: Do you see a slash being added in my suggested rule? That is due to one of your existing rule. If you post your complete .htaccess I can suggest you something.

Comment: Here it is:
`RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ getfile.php?hash=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: That rule also cannot add a trailing slash. You have other rules OR some other .htaccess in other directories.

Comment: There is no other `.htaccess` in folders `localhost` and `example`. And I post my whole `.htaccess`.

Comment: You need to understand few things. 1. None of these rules are doing redirect so URL cannot change (it will be routed internally). 2. None of these rules are adding any trailing slash either. So take your time and search your system with code/rules that is changing URL externally.